# What exactly is the SBAR label from the Penn TreeBank?

Tags: syntax, terminology, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

From this [list of tags](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/PennTreebankTags.html#SBAR):

> **SBAR** - Clause introduced by a (possibly empty) subordinating
>   conjunction.

This [site](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.html) explains what a subordinating conjunction is.  But how can you have an empty subordinating conjunction?  What are examples of sentences that should be SBAR not just S?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be being thrown by "clause", which need not mean "sentence". Consider the following pair of sentences.

(1) [**S** I can't believe [**SBAR** *that* John went without me.]]

(2) [**S** I can't believe [**SBAR** __ John went without me.]]

In both cases we have a sentence that contains a main and a subordinate clause. In (2), the subordinating conjunction (which goes by several other names as well, e.g. "complementizer") is "empty" (for various, theory-dependent definitions of *empty*).

Comment: Why don't they just call it a CP and be done with it?

Comment: The S and SBAR notation pre-dates the CP/IP/TP/etc phrasal node labels of recent/current incarnations of generative syntax.

Also, I believe, although I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong, that the computational linguists who first put together the Treebank & tagset (Marcus et al. 1992, I think?) weren't particularly inclined toward the theoretical direction of later-GB, and opted for a slightly more theory-neutral approach (although I suppose that's up for debate).

Answer (score 0):

This link Might Help you: [Penn TreeBank II Tags](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/PennTreebankTags.html).
PS: As I don't have enough reputation to add this link as a comment, so I am posting link as a answer.